# piping a std::tuple into a function

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20

This is a mythical beast we discussed in [a previous question](/q/265724/75307):

```
template <typename F, class Tuple>
constexpr void operator|(Tuple&& t, F f) noexcept(noexcept(f(std::get<0>(t))))
{
  [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept(noexcept(f(std::get<0>(t))))
  {
    (f(std::get<I>(t)), ...);
  }
  (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>());
}
```

Usage:

```
std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, 3) | [](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << std::endl; };
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/WMd80R2njgpubRvi

You could pipe all sorts of things into a function, not just a tuple. Arrays, containers, variants, ..., even structs.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a great need for this in normal (clear, obvious) code;
I believe that most C++ users would expect an ordinary function (in the pattern of `std::for_each()`, perhaps), rather than overloading the `|` operator.  In the future, `|` become recognised as a composition operator, but that is not the case in 2021, and so it will be harder for readers to comprehend than the plain function. This is clearly a matter of opinion where reasonable folk may differ, of course, and will likely change as time passes.

I suppose it's *arguably* similar to `| std::views::transform()` - except that it can only be a sink of values, because it returns `void` instead of a tuple of the results.  If `f()` returns `void`, that may be appropriate, but when `f()` is a value-returning function, we'll want access to those results (perhaps to pipe into another transform).

Why are we not perfect-forwarding the tuple elements?  I'm not convinced that this will work with functions that accept (mutable) references and update the values.

No unit tests are presented.  I would expect quite a large suite of tests for a template function such as this, and they should have been in the review request.  I certainly wouldn't accept this code into a project unless the tests were in the same submission.

Comment: we could accommodate all of these concerns, I suppose, by optionally returning another tuple. But this is not a serious idea.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would recommend - but only when `f()` applied to _all_ the input types is non-void (remember it can have many overloads).  It's probably simpler to just convert the tuple to a `std::array<std::variant>` and then use a transform using `std::visit`.

Comment: a return value could also indicate, that a conditional pipe is desired, i.e. stop piping when the return value is `true` or `false`.

Comment: But when you say piping `std::tuple`s is unclear, I don't see any clear/standard ways of doing this.

Comment: I believe that most C++ users would expect an ordinary function (in the pattern of `std::for_each()`, perhaps), rather than overloading the `|` operator.  As I said in the other question, `|` may _in future_ become recognised as a composition operator, but it is not so in 2021.  That's clearly a matter of opinion where reasonable folk may differ, so I don't see any value in arguing the point!

Comment: Someone needs to write a well thought-out library along the lines of `<ranges>`. Until then we are free to roll our own thing.

Answer (score 3):

## Incorrect `noexcept` clause

In the `noexcept` clause, you are only checking if the function applied to the first element of the tuple is `noexcept`. But overloads that handle the other elements might not be. So we need to check that they are *all* `noexcept`. The OP's code in the previous question handled this correctly.

## Use concepts

The problem with your `operator|()` is that it matches a lot of things that it shouldn't. It would be better to make it match only `std::tuple`s and other things that you can use `std::get<>()` for the first argument, and function-like things that accept the types in the tuple as the second argument.